# Call an Action from another Action instead of returning any simple result

Tags: java, web-services, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
def testSession = Action {
    implicit request =>
      val currentTimes = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
      val validTimes = Long.parseLong(request.session.get("validTill").getOrElse("0"))
      if(currentTimes>validTimes)
      {
        Ok("Session expired, Please log-in again")
      }
      else
      {
       //insert code here to call def saveDemographicDetailsBrowser = Action{}
      }
```

I need to insert code in else section to call some other action if login has not expired. An action that receives the json and hit save the data in db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to call an action from another Action then that simply means you have a wrong design. IMHO in such cases you should have a method which does the core functionality and both the Action's should make call to that method.

Anyways if you wish to make a call to another Action, then you could redirect:

```
Redirect(routes.Dashboard.homePage)
```

If the question is that you wish to make a call to Action by putting a new json in your request and then using this request to make a call to `Action`, then that is seriously inadvisable and still if you wish to then have a look at [FakeRequest](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/test/FakeRequest.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, such kind of session validations should go into RequestHandler/ActionCreator or Action composition.  With this approach, you can intercept the request to validate session expired cases and send the appropriate message,  even before the request reaches to your action.

Depending on your play framework version, you can check the following

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionCreator#Action-creators