# Can we get value from action methods in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

Here I have a action method,

```
 def foo = SecuredAction { implicit request=>
      val someImpData:String = request.someData
      Ok(someImpData)
    }
```

is there any way to run this method and get the "Hello" value in a variable, like:

```
val someVal:String = foo// hoping someVal will have value "Hello" after this line
```

It needs to be an action method, more specifically SecuredAction(SecureSocial) since implicit request objects are allowed only in controllers/action methods. So was searching for a way to get the body text from the **response**.

Comment: Result of `Action` is not a String there, but a `SimpleResult` with some content type (e.g. HTML). If you need access to underlying model, you'd rather not getting it through an `Action`. What's unclear there is why you need `request` to get the raw value.

Comment: So, there isn't a way at all of retrieving the response body from the action foo?? I needed to retrieve data which is there only in the request object and to access the request object the method needs to be an action method with implicit request. I am new to scala and play, so if you do have any suggestions??

Comment: You misunderstood. I mean you shouldn't even try. If I understand, you ask that only because you need `request` to get the raw value. That's the really issue for me (design flaw). And question should be how to get the raw value without needing request (which btw erroneously bind your code to the Web layer).

Comment: Parsing response would require that be sure of the format result (either plain text or JSON), which is not currently the case. Then Play Action is async, so you're parsing will also (having to handle `Future`). Using such 'tricks' will just make the situation more complex than fixing the real underlying issue.

Comment: Well as mentioned by @applicius you shouldnt even try doing it. Its a wrong design. You might rather have the core functionality as a service and the controller just calls the service to get the string `hello`. You can then directly call that service. If you still wish to call Action, you might send a FakeRequest (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/test/FakeRequest.html)

Comment: @mane for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603688/call-an-action-from-another-action-instead-of-returning-any-simple-result/19603742#19603742

Comment: I just changed my whole workflow, but even though there should have been someway, anywayzz thank you for your insights guyz.